# Reading a file with integer and double value to sum

Tags: java

I have the following file

```
This file will t3est the pr0gram t0 ch3ck if the f1le contains 0.04 and 1000 
letters .4
also this file          makes no sense -88 at all. Test you program
7this       9.....
```

I want to read all the integer and double values. But my program is only able to read `1000-88`. Is there a better delimiter that could be used?

Here is my code

```
public static double sumNumbers(String filename) {

    Scanner s = null;
    try {
        s = new Scanner(new File(filename)).useDelimiter("\\s+");
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    while (s.hasNext()) {
        if (s.hasNextInt()) { 
            System.out.print(s.nextInt()); 
        } else {
            s.next();
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Whats the output you are expecting

Comment: @CoderNeji for now I just want too to read all the values ( double and integers). I want to sum all of them after reading.

Comment: You are only reading integers in your code. Just add another if to scan double.

Comment: @Codebender so in the while statement can I do `while(hasNextInt() && hasNextDouble()`?

Comment: @Mani You call `s.hasNextInt()` so you can not read double values.

Comment: Try the following regex: `([\-]*[0-9]*[\.]*[0-9]+)` in your `useDelimiter` method.

Comment: It will probably be easier to set the delimiter to match numbers followed by an optional decimal point followed optionally by more numbers. Then take that `String` and check if it is an integer or double.

Comment: @Jens
@Codebender
When I tried reading double. I still doesnot read values like `som3`

Comment: @Mani som3 is a string

Comment: @VirtualMichael it returns the following error `Invalid escape sequence (valid ones are  \b  \t  \n  \f  \r  \"  \'  \\ )`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check for double number as well. Try the following code. I just modified your code to add a check for double numbers inside while loop.

```
public static double sumNumbers(String filename) {
    Scanner s = null;
    try {
        s = new Scanner(new File(filename)).useDelimiter("\\s+");
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    while (s.hasNext()) {
        if (s.hasNextInt()) {
            System.out.println(s.nextInt());
        } else if (s.hasNextDouble()) {
            System.out.println(s.nextDouble());
        } else {
            s.next();
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

If you want the numbers in between the strings. The following code should work.

```
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(new File("TestScanner.txt")));
StringBuffer buff = new StringBuffer();
String line = null;
while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
    buff.append(line);
}
String result = buff.toString().replaceAll("[\\-]*[^0-9]+[\\.]*[^0-9]+", " ");
System.out.println(Arrays.asList(result.trim().split(" ")));
```

Comment: Yes, that works but it does not get numbers from string like `som3`.

Comment: @Mani - I have added the piece of code in my answer to retrieve the numbers in between the string as well.

Answer (score 1):

Considering you have already read the content of the file in a String, you can use regex to get the integer and double values

```
String content = <I assume you have content here>;
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("-?\\d+\\.?\\d*"); // you might need to tweak to get exactly what you want
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(content);
while (matcher.find()) {
    System.out.println(matcher.group(0));
}
```

Above will output following values

```
3
0
0
3
1
0.04
1000
4
-88
7
9. // you can always process it to remove the extra dot in the case
```

Comment: I am passing the file directly(using a main method). I dont think that is same as storing it in a String?

Comment: But you can always do that, right? here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/326390/how-to-create-a-java-string-from-the-contents-of-a-file

Answer (score 0):

This will print the numbers. you may want to change the pattern to match negative numbers and decimal number starting with `.`. I also matches the numbers in between the text.

```
    try 
    {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(new File("File name"));
        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\d+\\.{0,1}\\d*"); 
        while (scan.hasNext()) {
            Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(scan.next());
            while (matcher.find()) {
                System.out.println(matcher.group(0));
            }
        }
        scan.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {

    }
```

Comment: This would be a better pattern that matches your requirement `Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("[\\-\\+]{0,1}\\d*\\.{0,1}\\d+"); `

Answer (score 0):

with help of sir AKS's answer, this may do:

```
 public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {

        String content = "";
        Scanner s = new Scanner(new File(filename));
        while (s.hasNext()) {
            content = content + s.nextLine() + "\n";
        }
        System.out.println(content);
        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("-?\\d+\\.?\\d*"); // you might need to tweak to get exactly what you want
        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(content);
        while (matcher.find()) {
            System.out.println(matcher.group(0));
        }
    }
```